# Java multiple instance like enum

Tags: java

I want to know the best way to instanciate the same object a lot of times with custom parameters.
I'm making achievements, with a class Achievement:

```
public class Achievement implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Achievements achievement;
private boolean passed;
private final boolean showable;
private int score, multiplicator, max;
private String name, description;
private long userID;

public Achievement(Achievements achievement) {
    this.achievement = achievement;
    this.max = achievement.getMax();
    this.multiplicator = achievement.getMultiplicator();
    this.name = achievement.getName();
    this.description = achievement.getDescription();
    this.showable = achievement.isShowable();
}
```

And an enum, which has a lot of parameters

```
public enum Achievements implements Serializable{




CHANNELJOIN("Premier contact vocal", "Rejoindre un channel vocal", 1, 1, true),
FRIEND2("Un ami ?", "Être à 2 dans un channel vocal", 1, 1, true),
FRIEND5("Copains !", "Être à 5 dans un channel vocal", 1, 1, false),
FRIEND8("Monopole d'amis", "Être à 8 dans un channel vocal", 1, 1, false),
CHANNELTIME1("Parleur", "Passer 1 heure dans un channel vocal, non seul", 1, 60, false),
CHANNELTIME2("Parleur 2", "Passer 2 heures dans un channel vocal, non seul", 2, 60, false),
COMMAND1("Première découverte", "Faire une commande du bot", 1, 1, true),
COMMAND2("Commande 2", "Faire 10 commandes avec le bot", 10, 1, true);

private String name;
private String description;
private int max, multiplicator;
private boolean showable;

Achievements(String name, String description, int max, int multiplicator, boolean showable) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.max = max;
    this.multiplicator = multiplicator;
    this.showable = showable;
}
```

(Don't mind the content). So what I'm doing is making:

```
for(Achievements a : Achievements.values()){
 Achievement ach = new Achievement(a);
}
```

But is that method the most optimized ? Can I create just one class Achievement, without enum ? Thanks for yours comments.

Comment: what kind of constructor is this ? Achievement(Achievements achievement) {
    this.achievement = achievement;

Comment: "optimized" in which sense? Why don't you just use your enum?

Comment: Storing the reference to both `achievement` and its instance variables in `Achievement` seems like a smell

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create just one class Achievement, without enum?

Sure, why not:

```
public class Achievement {

    public static final Achievement CHANNELJOIN = new Achievement("Premier contact vocal", "Rejoindre un channel vocal", 1, 1, true);
    public static final Achievement FRIEND2 = new Achievement("Un ami ?", "Être à 2 dans un channel vocal", 1, 1, true);
    public static final Achievement FRIEND5 = new Achievement("Copains !", "Être à 5 dans un channel vocal", 1, 1, false);
    public static final Achievement FRIEND8 = new Achievement("Monopole d'amis", "Être à 8 dans un channel vocal", 1, 1, false);
    public static final Achievement CHANNELTIME1 = new Achievement("Parleur", "Passer 1 heure dans un channel vocal, non seul", 1, 60, false);
    public static final Achievement CHANNELTIME2 = new Achievement("Parleur 2", "Passer 2 heures dans un channel vocal, non seul", 2, 60, false);
    public static final Achievement COMMAND1 = new Achievement("Première découverte", "Faire une commande du bot", 1, 1, true);
    public static final Achievement COMMAND2 = new Achievement("Commande 2", "Faire 10 commandes avec le bot", 10, 1, true);

    private boolean passed;
    private final boolean showable;
    private int score, multiplicator, max;
    private String name, description;
    private long userID;

    public Achievement(String name, String description, int max, int multiplicator, boolean showable) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.max = max;
        this.multiplicator = multiplicator;
        this.showable = showable;
    }

    // more methods here, e.g. getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to repeat the fields of your enum in your class, just access them through the (immutable) achievement field (i.e. `myAchievement.getAchievementType().getMax()`).

```
public class Achievement implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final Achievements achievementType;
private boolean passed;
private long userId;
private int score;

public Achievement(Achievements achievementType, long userId) {
    this.achievementType = achievementType;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.score = 0;
    this.passed = false;
}

// getters
public Achievements getAchievementType() {
    return achievements;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

...
```

Also, I would consider renaming your `Achievements` enum to `AchievementType`, or similar.

I wouldn't suggest making public static instances of Achievement which are available from the `Achievement` class, like `Achievement.CHANNELJOIN`, since it looks like you want a separate Achievement instance for each user, and those will necessarily be singletons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is that I have immutable data for the achievement, like name or maximumScore, but I have also the currentScore, so I just don't know how to use it well. But I agree, with you, that was stupid to get all the values from Achievements enum, keeping the Achievements value is better. And for renaming Achievements enum, I don't think that's match, because my enum is a list of differents achievements that can be made, not a list of types.